# How to prove this limit converging?

Tags: limits, complex-numbers, riemann-zeta

How to prove the following limit is converging and is equal to $0$ Because when I tried to sketch the graph on [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sz4d5mftdb) while changing the variable a I don't seem to find it converging ?

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\Sigma_{r= 1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\cos(\ln(\frac{1}{r^a}))$$,where a $\in$ ${\rm I\!R}$ - $\{0\}$

How I obtained this question:

I did a little simplification to Zeta function, in the following way,

$\zeta(s) = \Sigma_{r=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{r^s} = r^{-s})$

I set s = $\frac{1}{2} + a \iota$ , a $\in$ ${\rm I\!R}$ - $\{0\}$

Now, $r^{-s} = r^{-\frac{1}{2} - a\iota} = r^{-\frac{1}{2}}\times r^{-a\iota} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}e^{\ln(r^{-a})\cdot\iota} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\cdot(\cos(\ln(\frac{1}{r^{a}}))+(\sin(\ln(\frac{1}{r^{a}})\iota)))$

Now, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis) states that

> Thus, if the hypothesis is correct, all the non-trivial zeros lie on the critical line consisting of the complex numbers 
>   1
>   /
>   2
>    + i t, where t is a real number and i is the imaginary unit

Someone on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110944/what-does-the-numerically-verified-part-of-the-riemann-hypothesis-tell-about-pri) stated

> the Riemann hypothesis is verified for the first 10 trillion zeroes

How did someone verify that?(I tried using cmath and mpmath together in python and it outputs a non-zero complex number for various values of s in $\zeta(s)$)

If a complex number z = $x+\iota y = 0$ then $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ provided $x,y \in $ ${\rm I\!R}$

So, considering only the real part of my simplification, I want to know how the summation tends to $0$(without the summation it is pretty clear that the limit tends to $0$ as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}} \to 0$).

In sum, I want to know,

(1) How it is verified for 1st 10 trillion zeroes

(2) How to prove the above limit as converging

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The sum is zero only for specific values of $a$, for which we have no analytical expression.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @YvesDaoust, I have misunderstood the statement with "Every complex number of the form 1/2 + ai is a non-trivial zero". And, if there are certain values of a for which the function is 0, how can we prove the limit to be 0?

Comment: Sorry, this was wrong. The series diverges for values of the real part below $1$. The zeroes are defined for the analytic continuation of the series. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It diverges because for $\Re(s) > 0$ (taking the real part of the following with  $s=1/2+i a$) $$\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}-\frac{(N+1)^{1-s}-1}{1-s}=\sum_{n=1}^N \int_n^{n+1}(n^{-s}-x^{-s})dx=\sum_{n=1}^N \int_n^{n+1}\int_n^x st^{-s-1}dtdx$$ which in absolute value is $$ \le \sum_{n=1}^N \int_n^{n+1} |s| x^{-\Re(s)-1}dx= \int_1^{N+1} |s| x^{-\Re(s)-1}dx=|s|\frac{(N+1)^{-\Re(s)}-1}{-\Re(s)}$$
The same argument shows that for $\Re(s) > 0$ $$\zeta(s)-\frac1{s-1}=\lim_{N\to \infty} (\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}-\frac{(N+1)^{1-s}-1}{1-s})$$

Also, again, the zeros of $\Re(\zeta(s))$ are not isolated, they are a bunch of curves traversing the critical strip, you can't locate the non-trivial zeros just from it.